# Phantomjs renders wrong snapshot size

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

We try to make a snapshot from different webpages using phantomjs (both resizable and fixed pages).
When we try to do so on wikipedia (page is resizable), viewport dimensions from client are ignored. 
The problem is in render, as we define viewport width and height.
Seems that Phantomjs first stretches the page slightly (snapshot has a bit bigger text than original wikipedia), then it crops right margin, and adds large margin in the bottom.

Here is the code:

```
var oWebpage = Webpage.create();

oWebpage.viewportSize = {
    width  : nViewportWidth,
    height : nViewportHeight
};

oWebpage.onLoadFinished = function() {
    if (oWebpage.injectJs('inject.js')) {
        // nothing is being done to affect page size in inject.js
        try {
            oWebpage.evaluate(function() {
                // nothing is being done to affect page size here either
            });
            oWebpage.render(sImagePath, {format: 'png', quality: '100'});
            phantom.exit();
        } catch (oError) {
            phantom.exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
};

oWebpage.open(sMyUrl, function(sStatus) {
    if (sStatus != 'success') {
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
});
```

We tried to get document size and window size within evaluate() code, they both are equal to viewport size that comes from client.

We tried to play with page.zoomFactor, it didn't help.
Cliprect also doesn't help, it just cuts the page, but it's already resized on snapshot.

On all other pages that we tried it works perfect, and only on Wikipedia the behaviour is so strange. Just weird.
Have anyone had such issues?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the problem on wikipedia page was in its css.
It contained properties with 'vw' value, which was treated by Phantom incorrectly. It is not pixel value, but percentage from Viewport.
The only workaround was to parse css and get rid of 'vw' properties.

Though, after all done Phantom suddenly just stopped to work. Switched to NightmareJs - at least it is stable.